# Questions Keep repeating on my java app

Tags: java, android

Im a beginner so please bear with me
My java application has a questions class that i set up with 10 questions, the questions are set to be random but they keep repeating. I tried shuffle but it made no difference, what i wanted was for the questions to show once and the quiz would end after 10 questions
here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button answer1, answer2, answer3;
TextView Score, Question;

private Questions mQuestions = new Questions();

private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionsLength = mQuestions.mQuestions.length;

Random r;

List<Questions> list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    r = new Random();

    answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);

    Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
    Question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);

    Score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));

    list= new ArrayList<Questions>();

    Collections.shuffle(list);

    answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (answer1.getText()== mAnswer) {
                mScore++;
                Score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
            }else {
                gameOver();
             }
        }
    });

    answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (answer2.getText()== mAnswer) {
                mScore++;
                Score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
            }else {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    });

    answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (answer3.getText()== mAnswer) {
                mScore++;
                Score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
            }else {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void updateQuestion(int num) {
    Question.setText(mQuestions.getQuestion(num));
    answer1.setText(mQuestions.getChoice1(num));
    answer2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice2(num));
    answer3.setText(mQuestions.getChoice3(num));

    mAnswer = mQuestions.getCorrectAnswer(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, none of your questions are being removed from the list, just 'updated'.

Comment: How would i go about removing questions?

Comment: I see two methods, remove by index and remove by object. As long as an object only appears once in the list, these methods should be identical in function and might only differ in performance (if that.) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/List.html -> remove.

Comment: Ultimately I think you might not want to *remove* questions as much as move them to an "answered" list (remove from one list, add to the other) but if you don't care about more than the score once a question is answered, removal should be enough. Then you would need special handling for the behavior when the list is empty. If you care about being able to change your answer to previous questions, etc., then go with the two-list approach (or something comparable.)